# How to infer the generic type to avoid unchecked casting

Tags: java, generics

Suppose we have a class A that has two subclasses A1, A2.
Suppose we have another class B, that also has two subclasses, B1 an B2:

```
class B{
  List<? extends A> myGenericList;

  B(List<? extends A> myGenericList){
    this.myGenericList = myGenericList;
  }

  public List<? extends A> getMyGenericList(){
    return myGenericList;
  }
}

class B1 extends B{
  B1(List<A1> a1List){
    super(a1List);
  }
}

class B2 extends B{
  B2(List<A2> a2List){
    super(a2List);
  }
}
```

Now, if we have a class C1 like this:

```
class C1{
   ...

   public void doSomethingWithB1(B1 b1){
      List<A1> a1list = (List<A1>)b1.getMyGenericList();
   }

   ...
}
```

How can I implement getMyGenericList of class B so I can avoid the unchecked casting warning?

I tried something like this:

```
public <T extends A> List<T> getMyGenericList() {
    return this.myGenericList;
}
```

but the compiler complains with `cannot convert from List<capture#3-of ? extends A> to List<T>`

Is there any way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `List<? extends A> a1list = b1.getMyGenericList();`

Comment: @RahulSharma note that you can't add elements to the list with that idiom, though.

Comment: Or make the class B generic: `class B<T extends A> {
  List<T> myGenericList; }` ; `class B1 extends B<A1>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the current way you've defined the `B` class, the `myGenericList` instance variable could hold a List of any subtype of A, so the unchecked cast warning you get when casting to `List<A1>` is justified.  It could be a `List<A>` or a `List<A2>`.

If you don't really care which `A` you get in the list back, you can just assign it to a `List<? extends A>`.

```
List<? extends A> a1list =  b1.getMyGenericList();
```

But if you really want to get a `List<A1>` back from a `B1`, then generics on the `B` class is your answer.  Define `T` at the class level with an upper bound of `A`.  Use it throughout your class to replace your wildcards.

```
class B<T extends A>
{
  List<T> myGenericList;

  B(List<T> myGenericList){
    this.myGenericList = myGenericList;
  }

  public List<T> getMyGenericList(){
    return myGenericList;
  }
}
```

Your subclasses of `B` will define what `T` is respectively.

```
class B1 extends B<A1>  // rest of class is the same

class B2 extends B<A2>  // rest of class is the same
```

This way you have eliminated the unchecked cast warning and even the need to cast at all.

```
List<A1> a1list = b1.getMyGenericList();
```

Comment: Thanks @AlexR and rgettman for your answers. I will test them today

Answer (score 0):

You should move your generic definition to class level as following:

```
class B<T extends A> {
  List<T> myGenericList;

  B(List<T> myGenericList){
    this.myGenericList = myGenericList;
  }

  public List<T> getMyGenericList(){
    return myGenericList;
  }
}
```

Now the subclass is defined with concrete parameter `A1`:

```
class B1 extends B<A1>{
  B1(List<A1> a1List){
    super(a1List);
  }
}
```